# How to use play reverse routing in coffee script

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am new to play framework, coffee script and others so I am working on sort of POC project. But what I don't like is "hardcoded" routes in coffee script part of my project as follows:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
   <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
   <input id="tags">
</div>
```

Coffee script

```
$field = $('.ui-widget input')
$field.autocomplete ( minLength: 2, source: (response) -> $.get "/recommend/" + $field.val())
```

Is there a way how to get a "/recommend/" from play reverse route feature using play 2.0 ?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can generate a JavaScript router embedded in templates or as a separate action that you can include in your html as described in the docs here:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.0/ScalaJavascriptRouting